# Prove that $F(n+3)=2F(n+1)+ F(n)$ for $n \ge 0$

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

The definition of a Fibonacci number is as follows:

$$F(0)=0\\
F(1)=1\\
F(n)= F(n-2)+F(n-1)\text{ for }n\geq 2$$

Prove the given property of the Fibonacci numbers directly from the definition.
$F(n+3)=2F(n+1)+ F(n)$ for $n$ greater than or equal to $0$.

To get started:
-I would do a direct proof.

Assume that $F(0)=0$; $F(1)=1$; $F(n)= F(n-2)+F(n-1)$ for $n$ greater than or equal to $2$.

I am lost. Can I have a clue on the nest step?

Answer (score 4):

$$
F(n+3) = \color{red}{F(n+2)} + \color{blue}{F(n+1)} = \color{red}{F(n+1)} + \color{red}{F(n)} + \color{blue}{F(n+1)} = \color{green}{2F(n+1)} + \color{red}{F(n)}
$$

Answer (score 2):

First, show that $F(3) = 2F(1) + F(0)$, and that $F(4) = 2F(2) + F(1)$, using the definition directly, given your definition:

$$F(0)=0;\; F(1)=1;\quad F(n)= F(n-2)+F(n-1) \quad \text{for n greater than or equal to 2.}$$

We use the definition to express $F(n+3)$ in terms of $$\begin{align} F((n+3) - 2) & = F(n + 1)\\ \\ F((n+3) - 1) & = F(n+2)\end{align}$$

---

Now, we "unpack" $F(n+3)$ and express it as a function of $F(n + 1), F(n + 2)$:

$$\begin{align} {\bf F(n+3)} & = {\bf F(n+1)} + \underbrace{\left( F(n+2)\right)}_{\large = F(n) + F(n+1)} \\ \\
& \\ \\
& = {\bf F(n+1)}+ \left( F(n) + {\bf F(n+1)}\right)   \\ \\
& = {\bf 2 F(n+1)} + F(n)\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use the defining property that you listed to rewrite $F_{n+3}$ in terms of $F_{n+2}$ and $F_{n+1}$.